# Запятая перед "как", в значении "также как"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

> Забытый как правда.

Нужна запятая?

Comment: В отсутствие контекста эти слова звучат странно. Как будто все знают, что правда забыта(?!), а *его* постигла та же участь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Для ответа желательно присутствие контекста, а пока это выглядит как **словосочетание, а не предложение.** Поэтому сложно судить о значении оборота **как правда,** да и структуру предложения хотелось бы  видеть.

2) Вообще говоря, перед сложным (нерасчлененным) союзом ***так же как*** запятая ставится. Розенталь: Наша группа досрочно сдала все зачёты, так же как параллельная — без расчленения сложного союза; [См. § 34, п. 1.] http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

3) Но существует, к примеру, устойчивое выражение ***прост как правда,*** там запятой нет.

Но это, вероятно,  не наш случай, то есть здесь устойчивого сочетания нет, поэтому запятая, скорее всего, ставится.